# React-virtualized and components lifecycle management

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

Using MultiGrid component with loaded list of items.

For each item its state is initialized in react component constructor.

In the beginning list has 1 item. 
Then additional items are loaded and first item from the beginning goes to the end of list.

The problem is that after additional list items are loaded constructor for the first element (from loaded list) is not called. And current first element gets state from the 'first item' (the only item) from the beginning.

Do I miss something while using react-virtualized?